# Using sed command to find the first occurrence of the pattern and append

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

Say there is a text file as below:

```
Hello world
types=""
Mario
types="Game"
```

All I want to do is find the first occurrence of `type=""` and append with word `program`

My desired output:

```
Hello world
types="program"
Mario
types="Game"
```

I Need to use in Unix shell scripting.

What I tried:

```
sed -i  '1,/types=\"\"/s/types=\"\"/types=\"program\"/' filename
```

This command only inserting and  not appending. Tried adding `a\` but still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POSIXly:

```
$ sed -e '1,/types=""/{
  //s/"/&program/
}
' file
```

It's strange that above fail on GNU sed, you need:

```
$ sed -e '1,/types=""/{
  /types=""/s/"/&program/
}
' file
```

All above fail if `types=""` appear at the first line. In that case, you can use GNU sed or BSD sed `0,/pattern/`:

```
$ sed -e '0,/types=""/{                
  /types=""/s/"/&program/
}
' file
```

or POSIX one:

```
$ sed -e '/types=""/{
  s/"/&program/
  :1
  n
  b1
}
' file
```

or see [@mikeserv's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/208424/38906).

Comment: I get this error {sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression}

Comment: @VRVigneshwara: What's your sed version? you need to use the second if you use GNU sed.

Comment: `1,/types=""/` doesn't work if `types=""` is on the first line (that is, `sed` starts looking for `types=""` from the second line, and thus you get the first _two_ `types=""` replaced).  A solution is to use `0,/types=""/`, but the `0` address is not accepted by all `sed`s.  It's ok for GNU `sed`, and for *BSD `sed` though.

Comment: @lcd047: Good point. Updated!

Comment: @cuonglm Last one aced it ! but it's printing below after executing the command . How can it be avoided?

Comment: @VRVigneshwara: What do you mean printing below?

Comment: After command is executed the corrected file details are displayed below. Which i want to avoid it

Comment: @VRVigneshwara: With GNU sed, you can use `sed -i.bak` to make the changes inplace to file.

Comment: @mikeserv: You mean there's *no* previous address?

Answer (score 4):

```
{   sed '/types=""/!b
        s/"/&program/;q'
    cat
}   <infile >outfile
```

A POSIX `sed` will leave its input file offset exactly where it `q`uits input. With GNU `sed` you might need the `-u` option, though.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `i` to insert, then `d` to delete the line, and `q` to quit:

```
~$ sed '/types=""/{i\
> types="program"
> d;q}' f
Hello world
types="program"
Mario
types="Game"
```

---

The following doesn't work (thanks @mikeserv):
or simply `c` to change the line, and `q` to quit:

```
~$ sed '/types=""/{c\
> types="program"
> q}' f
Hello world
types="program"
Mario
types="Game"
```

(and of course keep the `-i` for in place)